# GLMM- Is it possible to limit variable combinations?

Tags: r, lme4

Let's assume I want to see all possible variable's combinations of a GLMM (using `lme4`) but I don't want to consider two variables at the same time in a model. How do I do that? For instance, I want to consider 3 fixed effects and 3 random effects, but I don't want any of the random or fixed effects to be considered at the same time in a model. If I construct the model this way:

```
model1 <- glmer(x~var1+var2+var3+(1|var4)+(1|var5)+(1|var6),
 data=data1)
```

and I use `MuMIn::dredge()` function (to perform model averaging later), I will get all possible combinations between them, but I don't want `(1|var4)` to be in the same model as `(1|var5)`.

So, is it possible to limit model combinations? This way I would avoid unnecessary models and save computing time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just in case anyone is looking for an updated solution to this... You can now do this easier with the [subset](https://rdrr.io/cran/MuMIn/man/dredge.html) argument of dredge:

```
#full model
model1 <- glmer(x~var1+var2+var3+(1|var4)+(1|var5)+(1|var6),data=data1)
#exclude models containing both (1|var4) & (1|var5) at the same time
dredge(model1, subset = !((1|var4) && (1|var5)))
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to do this within `MuMIn::dredge()` (but see my attempts below).

```
 set.seed(101)
 dd <- data.frame(x=rnorm(1000),
                 var1=rnorm(1000),
                 var2=rnorm(1000),
                 var3=rnorm(1000),
                 var4=sample(factor(sample(1:20,size=1000,replace=TRUE))),
                 var5=sample(factor(sample(1:20,size=1000,replace=TRUE))),
                 var6=sample(factor(sample(1:20,size=1000,replace=TRUE))))
 library(lme4)
 m0 <- lmer(x~var1+var2+var3+(1|var4)+(1|var5)+(1|var6),dd,REML=FALSE,
            na.action=na.fail)
```

If we try to use the `m.lim` argument it subsets only the fixed effects, but leaves in all the random effect terms:

```
dredge(m0,m.lim=c(0,1))
## Model selection table 
##   (Intrc)      var1     var2    var3 df    logLik   AICc delta weight
## 1 0.02350                             5 -1417.485 2845.0  0.00  0.412
## 3 0.02389           -0.03256          6 -1416.981 2846.0  1.02  0.248
## 5 0.02327                    0.02168  6 -1417.254 2846.6  1.56  0.189
## 2 0.02349 -0.002981                   6 -1417.480 2847.0  2.02  0.151
## Models ranked by AICc(x) 
## Random terms (all models): 
## ‘1 | var4’, ‘1 | var5’, ‘1 | var6’
```

Following `demo(dredge.subset)`, I tried this as an example:

```
dredge(m0,
     subset=expression(!( (var1 && var2) || ((1|var4) && (1|var5)))))
```

but got

```
Error in dredge(m0, subset = expression(!((var1 && var2) || ((1 | var4) &&  : 
  unrecognized names in 'subset' expression: "var4" and "var5"
```

I can't find any documentation on how to do dredging/model averaging with `MuMIn::dredge()` across models with different random effects (indeed, I'm not convinced this is a good idea).  *If* you wanted to fit all models with exactly one fixed-effect and exactly one random-effect term, you could do it as follows:

Set up all combinations:

```
fvars <- paste0("var",1:3)
gvars <- paste0("(1|var",4:6,")")
combs <- as.matrix(expand.grid(fvars,gvars))
```

Now fit them:

```
mList <- list()
for (i in 1:nrow(combs)) {
    mList[[i]] <- update(m0,
          formula=reformulate(combs[i,],response="x"))
}
```

Now you can use `lapply` or `sapply` to operate on the elements of the list, e.g.:

```
lapply(mList,formula)
## [[1]]
## x ~ var1 + (1 | var4)
## 
## [[2]]
## x ~ var2 + (1 | var4)
## 
## [[3]]
## x ~ var3 + (1 | var4)
## 
## [[4]]
## x ~ var1 + (1 | var5)
## ... et cetera ...

bbmle::AICtab(mList,weights=TRUE)
##        dAIC df weight
## model5 0.0  4  0.344 
## model6 0.5  4  0.262 
## model4 1.0  4  0.213 
## model8 4.1  4  0.044 
## ... et cetera ...
```

... but you'll have to work a bit harder to do model averaging. You might try `r-sig-mixed-models@r-project.org`, `r-sig-ecology@r-project.org`, or e-mail the maintainer of `MuMIn` (`maintainer("MuMIn")`) ...

Comment: Thank you very much Ben!! I'll contact them or maybe do all possible combinations and exclude the ones that don't matter; in excel it may be possible!